# filtering entity based on related entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an `Event` entity:

```
public class Event
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public AppUser Creator { get; set; }
        public int CreatorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MainPhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserEvents> Organisers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EventPhoto> Photos { get; set; }  
    }
```

I have created a join table entity called `UserEvents`:

```
 public class UserEvents
    {
        public AppUser Organiser { get; set; }
        public int OrganiserId { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }
        public int EventId { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to only retrieve the `Event` entities where the user is one of the organizers. This is the method I have created in my repository file. Note, the following code is invalid, I know this. I just want to give you an idea of what I am trying to achieve:

```
 public async Task<PagedList<EventDto>> GetPaginatedEventsAsync(EventParams eventParams)
 {
   var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByUsernameAsync(eventParams.username);
    
   var events = _context.Events
   .AsQueryable()
   .Where(organisers => organisers.Organiser.Id == user.Id)
   .ProjectTo<EventDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
    
   return await PagedList<EventDto>.CreateAsync(events, eventParams.PageNumber, eventParams.PageSize);
    
 }
```

How would I filter the `Event` entity based on the related join table entity?

Comment: `.Where(evt => evt.Organisers.Any(organiser => organiser.Id == user.Id))`.

Comment: You are a star! This worked